# Symfony2 KnpMenuBundle children with dynamic parameters

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

Let's say I have a routing setup like that :

```
users_list:
    pattern:  /users
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:User:list }

user_edit:
    pattern:  /user-edit/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:User:edit }
```

I would like to setup a menu like this

- Home
- --Users list
- ----User edition

But I'm not sure how to handle my route 'user_edit' with dynamic params "id". Actually I don't want to display the link (which id ?), but **I would like the 'Users list' parent node to be active if I edit an user**.

I tried something like this

```
$userNode = $rootNode->addChild('Users list', array(
    'route' => 'users_list',
));
$userNode->addChild('User edition', array(
    'route' => 'user_edit',
));
```

Symfony complains about the missing parameter :(

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found something usefull in my case, you're able to solve this using the request in your menu definition class :

```
$userNode->addChild('User edition', array(
    'route' => 'user_edit',
    'routeParameters' => array('id' => $this->getRequest()->get('id'))
));
```

Answer (score 4):

This setup should work if you want to show the links:

```
$userNode->addChild('User edition', array(
    'route' => 'user_edit',
    'routeParameters' => array('id' => $someParameter)
));
```

For setting the parrent node as active you could use a custom renderer, override the menubundle's template or just add active class to the menu item based on this condition:

```
{% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'user_edit' %}
       {# activate parrent node #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yeah but then i create the link for a specific id, if I want the link to be "active" for any id specified I can't

Comment: app.request.attributes.get('_route') returns the name of the rout which is the same for any id used

Comment: Ok got it, so I have to make custom conditions for any "dynamic" route I have ? I'm actually trying to reproduce this for my entire backend

Comment: Hi @ThomasPiard interested to know if you found an elegant solution here?